Schengen visa appointment date is after visit date
We are from Armenia, and recently our Schengen visa appointment dates were given (we applied on Polands website).
We planned our visit to start from August 4, however the appointment date we received is August 5.
Will we be able to reschedule or do we have to cancel and apply for a different date?

How long is your intended visit? Are you just going to Poland for a holiday, or is the trip planned around a specific event? Why did you apply so close to your intended departure date?

@Traveller we applied last month, it took 3 weeks to get a date
